# Как отследить прекращение скролла?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Друзья, помогите, пожалуйста.

Есть код:
HTML:

`<div id="me">
       <img id="me_up" src="deep_space/me.png" alt="Me">
</div>`

JS:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(win).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (st > lastScrollTop){
        $('#me_up').attr('src', 'deep_space/me_up2.png'); //вниз
     }
     else {
        $('#me_up').attr('src', 'deep_space/me_up.png');// вверх 
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
    });
```

или такой:

```
$('body', 'html').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
        console.log(delta > 0 ?'up' : 'down');
        if (delta > 0) {
            $('#me_up').attr('src', 'deep_space/me_up.png');
        }
        else {
            $('#me_up').attr('src', 'deep_space/me_up2.png');
        }
    });
```

Код меняет картинку в зависимости от направления скроллинга. Но когда скроллить перестаешь, то картинка остается измененной и на исходную не меняется.

Собственно, вопрос:
Как отследить прекращение скролла? Хочу при прекращении скролла менять картинку на исходную.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @ezelen, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Долго переписывать.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling

Comment: Огромное спасибо!